# Given $R=1$ and the series diverges for $x=1$, can the series converge absolutely at $x=-1$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Given that the radius of convergence for a series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (a_nx^n)$ is $1$ and the series diverges for $x=1$, is it possible that the series converges absolutely at $x=-1$?

It sounds to me that this should be false since if it converges absolutely at $-1$, it should converge at $|-1| = 1$ and it doesn't.

Am I correct or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: Absolute convergence at $x=-1$ and at $x=+1$ both mean that $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}|a_n|$ is convergent.

Comment: You are correct

Comment: Thanks for the help, @AdityaDwivedi and @MartinR!

Comment: @MartinR Is it meant to be $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}|a_nx^n|$ or is the $x^n$ intentionally left out? Also, I assume this holds for any value of $R$ and not just $R=1$, is that correct?

Comment: @DenverCoder1: Absolute convergence of $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_nx^n$ at $x=-1$ means that $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} |a_n (-1)^n| = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}|a_n|$ is convergent.

Comment: @MartinR: Thanks, what would happen if the claim said "3" in place of everywhere it says "1", would it still be false? It doesn't seem to me like the same steps can be used.

Comment: @DenverCoder1: Absolute convergence at $x=3$ and $x=-3$ are equivalent, or generally at $x=+R$ and $x=-R$. – Is that what you mean?

Comment: @MartinR Thanks again!